# Using Simple Html Dom to extract bold text from a div

Tags: php, html, curl, simple-html-dom

Working on a script project, literally spent the last 4 hours on this researching everything I can - my head literally doesn't function anymore on this matter and really need your help.

So I have a PHP cURL script that grabs data from a website. I can grab div's that have ID's and all that. But how can I grab specific text from within a DIV that does not have any ID/class/or anything specific other than the fact that its the only bold item in the div?

Here is the HTML Text on the website:

```
<div class="firststyle"><label for="calculator" class="class-coll-1">
                <p class="sr-only">Welcome to the calculator:</p> <b>What is one plus two?</b> </label></div>
```

What I am trying to parse/extract from this HTML part is JUST the text "**What is one plus two?**".
How can define this specific part to be selected?

The only thing I can currently do is parse the entire div with the following script:

```
$html = str_get_html($response);
$the_question = $html->find('div[class=firststyle]');
```

However this gets all the text including the "Welcome to the calculator" label thing which I don't need.

Would it be possible to maybe somehow save the parsed data into a variable, and then go from that use a different script to extract the data from that variable?

Or maybe can I do something like:

*Find div with this ID -> find bold text within it*

Or maybe:

*Find div with ID -> take out the text "Welcome to calculator"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $html->find('.firststyle b', 0)->innertext;
#=> What is one plus two?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the HTML from the website you can use the DOMDocument class to parse it.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

The DOMDocument class ships with a lot of methods. These are the two you're going to need `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName`.

Something like this:

```
$html = '<div id="test"><b>I want to be found!</b></div><div id="poep"><b>Im not selected</b></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$div = $dom->getElementById('test');
$text = $div->getElementsByTagName('b')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $text;
```

Will output:

```
I want to be found!
```